# Uppaal - How to force a transition when a condition becomes true?

Tags: formal-verification, model-checking, uppaal

I would like to be able to force a transition as soon as a condition becomes true.

For example in this [Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5kWyM.png), I would like to force the transition from the system next from the state *S0* to *S1* as soon as the global variable *a* becomes *5*. The guard is not enough because a can still be incremented once it reach 5 before the transition is fired. I really need the transition to be triggered and then continue to increment *a*.

Is there a simple way to do it? I tried by adding invariant in the state but it is creating deadlocks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use channel synchronization. Several approaches:

1. declare `chan message;` and add `message!` synchronization on the `increment` process, add `message?` on the `next` process transition, and use another transition with the guard to check the value of `a` and move to another location accordingly.
2. declare `urgent broadcast chan ASAP;` and use `ASAP!` on the `next` edge, this will make this transition urgent as soon it becomes enabled (i.e. the guard is satisfied). Only the integer guards are supported on urgent transitions.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add invariant `a<=5` in the S0 state.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: So when we add invariant to the states it is a forced update, but when we add a guard to the transitions it's not a forced update, right?